# Mixed ANOVA in R with unequal group sizes?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

Spoiler alert: My stats education stopped before ANOVA so everything that I know, I learned myself.

Design of data: I have 2 groups and a response variable is measured across multiple blocks in the same participants. There is also another within subject factor, the type of task that they did. Both groups underwent the same tasks in the same amounts and for the same number of blocks. I thought this was a mixed ANOVA. I used ezANOVA and aov functions but then realized that one of my participants had to be excluded. Now they both mysteriously stopped working.

How do I address this? Do I need to have equal groups for this to work or am I just missing some kind of correction that needs to be applied? I would appreciate tips or a direction to pursue...